# SQL Server - What is the correct syntax?

Tags: sql, if-statement, syntax, where-clause

Do I write the correct syntax?

pseudo code

```
select * from products
if @value is not null begin where category = @value end
+ if @value1 is not null begin where other1 = @value1 end
+ if @value2 is not null begin where other2 = @value2 end
+ if @value3 is not null begin where other3 = @value3 end
```

I am noob. I do not want to write a dynamic query. How to write the above query?

Comment: Is this a typo? Are the `@value` in the `ifs` supposed to be `@value1`, `@value2`, etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how you do it without using dynamic SQL

```
select * 
from products
where (@value is null or category = @value) 
       and (@value1 is null or other1 = @value1) 
       and (@value2 is null or other2 = @value2)
       and (@value3 is null or other3 = @value3)
```

**How does it work?**

Take this line `@value is null or category = @value`.

Above condition checks if @value is null.If it is, that whole line/condition evaluates as true. So we are ignoring the or part there.

Same applies to all other conditions.

Hope this makes it clear!